# dynamically nested array map using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of list keys like:

```
$list_map_key=[
  ['pn','pn1','pp','pp1'],
  ['pn','pn1','pp','pp2'],
  ['pn','pn2','pp','pp5'],
  ['pn','pn2'],
];
```

I want to build map key array like this to replace value of (pp)

```
$data_return['pn']['pn1']['pp']['pp1']=3000;

$data_return['pn']['pn1']['pp']['pp2']=3000;

$data_return['pn']['pn2']['pp']['pp5']=3000;

$data_return['pn']['pn2']=3000;
```

But the keys to the array $data_return['pn']['pn1']['pp']['pp1'] must be dynamically generated from the array key list.

I want to build some function to call position data from list array key and add, replace or delete data.

Comment: Please post your attempt together with proper examples of the expected result and what you're currently getting. Right now it's very unclear what you're trying to do or where you're stuck. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact output you want is not achievable since `$data_return['pn']['pn2']` cannot simultaneously be an array and a value. However you can achieve something similar with this code. The function `push_value` takes an array of keys and pushes the value into a multi-dimensional array according to those keys. Then we generate `$data_return` by looping over each individual value in `$list_map_key` and using `array_merge_recursive` to merge the individual arrays together:

```
function push_value($keys, $value) {
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if (count($keys)) {
        return array($key => push_value($keys, $value));
    }
    else {
        return array($key => $value);
    }
}
$data_return = array();
$value = 3000;
foreach ($list_map_key as $keys) {
    $data_return = array_merge_recursive($data_return, push_value($keys, $value));
}
print_r($data_return);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [pn] => Array
        (
            [pn1] => Array
                (
                    [pp] => Array
                        (
                            [pp1] => 3000
                            [pp2] => 3000
                        )
                )
            [pn2] => Array
                (
                    [pp] => Array
                        (
                            [pp5] => 3000
                        )
                    [0] => 3000
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gV6Bd)

Comment: thanks for answer my question. im try to change my question more close by my case ,can you help me one more time?

Comment: @yuanganteng that is a *completely* different question. You should put this back the way it was when I answered it and ask a new one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388342/dinamicaly-json-object-by-bluprint-array-map-list-for-return-array-1-dimention
sorry nick im newbe

Comment: @yuanganteng no worries - at all, we've all been there. I'll try to take a look at your new question tomorrow if no-one else has answered it.