# Dynamically json object by blueprint array map list for return array 1 dimension

Tags: php, json

i want return from query to json nested with blueprint nested json

this example from query with type array json 1 dimention

```
// return from query sql
    $data=[
        ['id_daerah'=>12,'nama'=>'bojonegoro','jumlah_kegiatan'=>100,'jumlah_program'=>3,'id_program'=>2],
        ['id_daerah'=>12,'nama'=>'bojonegoro','jumlah_kegiatan'=>100,'jumlah_program'=>3,'id_program'=>2],
        ['id_daerah'=>13,'nama'=>'mojo','jumlah_kegiatan'=>100,'jumlah_program'=>3,'id_program'=>2],
        ['id_daerah'=>13,'nama'=>'mojo','jumlah_kegiatan'=>100,'jumlah_program'=>3,'id_program'=>2],
        ['id_daerah'=>13,'nama'=>'mojo','jumlah_kegiatan'=>100,'jumlah_program'=>3,'id_program'=>2,

    ]



foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    # code...

    //  start blueprint map nested json key
    $array_map_list=[
        ['daerah',$value['id_daerah']],
        ['daerah',$value['id_daerah']],'program',$value['id_program'],
        ['daerah',$value['id_daerah']],'program',$value['id_program'],'kegiatan',$value['id_kegiatan'],

    ]
    // map nested object 3 level




    //  i need  function to handle this job return object json with nested blueprint (map nested key list)  



}
```

i want to return like this

```
$data_return=[
    'daerah'=>[
            12//id_daerah
            =>[
                'nama'=>'bojonegoro',
                'program'=>[
                    3 //id_program
                    =>[
                        'jumlah_kegiatan'=>200 // sum()  
                    ]

                ]

            ],
            13=>[

                'nama':'mojo',
                'program'=>[
                    3 //id_program
                    =>[
                        'jumlah_kegiatan'=>300 // sum()  
                    ]

                ]

            ]

        ]
]
```

i need some method to handle this job with dinamicaly just change blueprint map nested list return will follow that blueprint.

i use $data_return['daerah'][$value['id_daerah']]..... = array(.....)
but its static proccess

im stuck thinking how to proccess will be dynamicly

Comment: my mean im stuck

im try use $data_return['daerah'][$value['id_daerah']]=array('nama'=>.....) but its static process im stuck trying thinking, how to proccess will be dinamic